# fetch all null values for a object django

Tags: django

How should I search for all  null values for a  given object (name)?

```
model:
name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True,blank=True)
u_name=models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True,blank=True)
year=models.PositiveSmallInteger(blank=True,null=True)
```

I am looking to back populate some data through various 'lookups'. 
It may or may not have value for various fields for a given object. I want to populate those fields that are null with the available values through lookups. 

I can fetch one field that is null. But is there a way fetch all the null values for a give name 'rig'

```
u_name = Name.objects.filter(name='rig', u_name__isnull=True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that CharFields will store 'null' values as empty strings (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null), so you may want to try the following:

```
u_name = Name.objects.filter(name='rig').filter(u_name=None)
```

or

```
u_name = Name.objects.filter(name='rig').filter(u_name="")
```

Update based on comments:

To get the Names with name='rig':

```
rigs = Name.objects.filter(name='rig')
```

then loop over empty `u_names`:

```
for u_name in rigs.filter(u_name=""):
    # do things
```

and then loop over empty `year`s:

```
for empty_year in rigs.filter(year=None):
    # do things
```

Comment: So if I have to find any null value for a given name 'rig', I should be using OR '|' operator ? for example if I have to do this in django SELECT * from user where name = 'rig' and  u_name is null or year is null . Does this translate to this in django ?! User.objects.filter(name='rig').filter(u_name=None) | User.objects.filter(name='rig').filter(year=None). Can we do this in a single query ?!

Comment: TBH - I think your original query should have worked, though I think your issue is that CharFields are never NULL when using the Django ORM. Try `u_name = Name.objects.filter(name='rig', u_name="")` and see whether that returns what you need. Otherwise you'll have to drop to [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: Sorry, just reread about your OR filter. You're correct: use the | to get all the results in one go. Or you could do `rigs = User.objects.filter(name='rig')` and then use that in two loops for your updating. E.g. `for null_name in rigs.filter(u_name=None): ...` and `for null_year in rigs.filter(year=None): ...`. How that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot thats perfect.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if this works for you.